# QTKit audio mute and Stream Buffering status message 

Tags: cocoa, qtkit

I'm muting volume in QTkit like this:

```
if
            ([muteButton state] == NSOnState){


    [mMovieVolumeSlider setFloatValue:0.1];
    [testMovie setVolume:0.1];
```

The problem is the volume attenuation is sudden and abrupt. How can I implement a fade effect to the volume attenuation?

Also - my app runs .pls audio stream files. I have the .pls files embedded in the bundle. When selecting a stream within the app, a short delay is common before the stream begins to play. I want to display some sort of status message ("Buffering" or Connecting") during this short delay prior to connecting. When the stream begins the status message would end. Any idea's on how to approach this?

thanks for the help.

-paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just outline my answers to your two questions as suggestions:

1. What you want to accomplish sounds much like a good fit for [NSAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAnimation/initWithDuration%3aanimationCurve%3a) (either through subclassing or delegation — [`animation:valueForProgress:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSAnimationDelegate/animation%3avalueForProgress%3a) will probably be your friend here).
2. Open the QTMovie asynchronously and listen for the [QTMovieLoadStateDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002391-SW176).

HTH

Daniel